# Flat lines in Fast Fourier Transform using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have data of 500 years with data point for every year.
The data in numpy array is [here](https://gofile.io/?c=26FmEk)

Looking at the data there is a clear signal of 100 years, however, when I'm doing the Fourier transform I get two flat lines in the plot which I can't understand why they are there.

The plot looks like that:

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft, rfft, fftfreq
import pylab as plt

sig = np.load('fft.npy')
sig = sig.squeeze()/(80*60) # Grid scaling
x = np.arange(1,501,1)

W = fftfreq(sig.size, d=(x[1]-x[0]))

plt.figure(figsize=(7,3.5))
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(x,sig)
plt.xlabel('Time (years)')

f_sig = fft(sig)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(W, abs(f_sig)**2)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (1/year)')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim(10**(-3), 1)
plt.show()
```

Why there are two flat lines on the frequency plot? Why don't I see clearly the 100 yr frequency?

Comment: Some of the frequencies will be negative, so plotting them on a log scale won't work well. The lower line looks like it is connecting the last positive frequency with the first negative one. I'd recommend using rfft and rfftfreq instead.

Comment: Is the log scale on the y axis making the peak at W = 0.01 look small?

Comment: Thank you! Interesting. I tried using `rfft` and it got rid of the lower line. I still don't understand why the upper line is there.

Comment: What upper line?

Comment: The upper flat line to the left of the 10^(-2) frequency.

Comment: that's probably because the first element of W is 0, which gets mapped to -infinity by the log scale.